# Store contents of a tag in Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning Javascript and I  am trying to learn some pretty basic stuff. Basically I have some text in a `<p>` tag which I want to append to a variable. However it is not working an I'm not sure why. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = $('p').html();
  document.write(x);
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="first">Hello World  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: By the way, avoid `document.write` - use `console.log` and your browser's Console (e.g. Web Console or Firebug in Firefox) for test output. To print to a page it's better to use other DOM methods (e.g. via `$(...).text()`)

Comment: Also, it makes a better question when you state specifically what you see and what you expected to see (i.e. "I get null printed before the `<p>` tag instead of a duplicate parameter"). In this case your expectations were clear, but often they aren't.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your code in [`$.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  var x = $('p').html();
  document.write(x);
});

</script>
```

The ready handler fires after DOM has loaded and parsed meaning only then you can maipulate tags (or DOM).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything what isn't working ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Sxtz/))

maybe you should write

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //your javascript code
})
```

but if it doesn't work with that either I should remind you that `document.write` normally replaces the content

Answer (score 0):

You are running your script before The `<p class="first">Hello World</p>` is reached in your HTML. Put your script in the body instead just after the `<p>` tag:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <p class="first">Hello World</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var x = $('p').html();

            document.write(x);
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can also use jQuery's ready function like some others have said, but that's an inefficient solution since you already know at which point in the document the `<p>` tag is loaded. It's much better to run your script as soon as it's loaded then to wait for the whole document to load using `$.ready`.

Comment: That's not universally true and I think it's too much information for a beginner's question.

Comment: It's not always better to avoid $.ready. For example, in this very case (ignoring special document.write behaviour during the page load) there's no efficiency benefit in using inline `<script>` as opposed to a `$.ready`, while $.ready allows you to put all the JS in one place (e.g. in an external file).